# How to adjust navbar to a fixed width in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Default navbar spans horizontally across the browser window.

`<div class="navbar navbar-static-top">`

How do you declare the navbar to be only `750px` width and placed at the center?
Setting `margin:auto;` in the CSS doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.navbar-static-top` you are using forces your navbar to become full-width. Remove that class and you will get a resizable navbar. Then, you can wrap it in a `span#` of the size you want:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <div class="navbar">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here you have an example: http://jsfiddle.net/simbirsk/xAMYF/

Comment: thanks, that was helpful. id also like to ask how to disable the curve sides?

Comment: Remove the following from anything you want to remove curved sides from:
-webkit-border-radius;
-moz-border-radius;
border-radius;

Comment: Don't remove styles! Overwrite them and the native navbar will continue available for any use. These are the styles: .navbar-inner {-webkit-border-radius: 0; -moz-border-radius: 0; border-radius: 0;}. Anyway, you should open a new question so others can benefit from the answers